# > (0 , _cypressCucumberPreprocessor.And) is not a function

Tags: cypress, cypress-cucumber-preprocessor

> (0 , _cypressCucumberPreprocessor.And) is not a function

[image]

Answer (score 5):

It's just a simple oversight, it means you are missing an import for `And` - any Cucumber keywords used in the test needs to be imported.

```js
import { Then, When, And } from "@badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor"
```

Answer (score 0):

your cypress is not fully installed. i had the same problem
run :

> npm i --force

after that you can run :

> npx cypress open